# Superscripts in bibliography with bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Is there a bibliography style (I'm using `bibtex`) that works with `article` class where the numbers appear as superscripts and also numbered as they appear in the text (as in `unsrt`)? I read some related questions using `revtex`, but nothing seem to work with basic `article` class.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The [cite package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite) provides such functionality and works with the standard bibliography styles such as `unsrt`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}

\begin{document}

Refering to second article\cite{art2} and then first article\cite{art1}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

with `test.bib` containing

```
@Article{art1,
  author =   {Author, A. N.},
  title =    {Title One},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     2000
}

@Article{art2,
  author =   {Author, A. N.},
  title =    {Title Two},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     2008
}
```

yields

[image: Sample output]

The first option `superscript` to the `cite` package affects the citations in the text, the second `biblabel` adjusts those in the bibliography.

Comment: This is just what is needed! 
To get the citings to have brackets around them, one has to use 

`\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@citess}[1]{\textsuperscript{\,[#1]}}
\makeatother`

Comment: For most people it will be obvious but it took me some time to figure out that I had to use `bibtex` instead of `biber` and did not have to import the `biblatex` package in order to run the `cite` package.

Comment: Is it possible to display the References as "Author AN. Title. Journal, 2008"?

Comment: @papgeo Yes it is possible.  It is controlled by the `\bibliographystyle`, so either you need to find a style that does this for you, or you can use [custombib / makebst](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) to create your own style.  If you get stuck, just ask a new question here, providing details of what you need and what you have tried.

Comment: Is it also possible to keep citation with upperscript while having the numbers in the reference list within brackets [1]?

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein You get this style with the natbib package.  See my answer, where have also added typical code and output.

Answer (score 32):

You could use the [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib) package and invoke it with the `super` option:

```
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
```

With this setup, `\cite` commands will generate citation markers as superscript-positioned numbers. Note that the `natbib` package is compatible with a wide range of bibliography style files, including the "original" BibTeX style files `plain`, `unsrt`, and `alpha`.

If you use the `hyperref` package as well, these superscript numbers will automatically be made into hyperlinks to the corresponding items in the bibliography.

Here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{auth,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

A citation \cite{auth}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: If you prefer commas between the citations superscripts you can use \usepackage[super,comma]{natbib}

Comment: `natbib` is perfect! `cite` will place the superscript after punctuation, the bibliography list entry number will also be superscript and it auto reorders citations by ascending number, whereas`natbib` does not have those issues.

Comment: @gaborous - Thanks! For the sake of completeness: If the `cite` package is used (instead of `natbib`), auto-reordering of the citation call-outs by ascending number can be disabled by specifying the `nosort` option.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without changing the behavior of the `citet` and `citep` commands? With this approach, the `citep` command prints just the superscript and the `citet` command prints the author names with a superscript, rather than the behavior described by [this page](http://merkel.texture.rocks/Latex/natbib.php).

Comment: @LukeDavis - The link you provide purports to describe what version 7.0b of the `natbib` package did, back in February 2002. The current version is 8.31b; it is my understanding that the package has been roughly stable since Sept. 2010. I'm afraid I don't know how one might go about downgrading the package back to its 2002 level.

Comment: @Mico Sorry I think I didn't explain what I wanted clearly; [here is a thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/420370/73149) I just started. That link was just to show you the default behavior of the `citet`/`citep` commands; it hasn't changed since 2002.

Answer (score 2):

While not 100% what your question asks for, biblatex has a function `\supercite` which is a drop-in replacement for `\cite` and does what you want

Comment: First of all: Thank you for your answer. However, you could improve it, by adding a minimal working example with bibliography (see, e.g., https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/277964 and don't care about this link is mostly about how to do it for questions) to your answer. This would help other users with similar problems to test it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Package "cite" places the superscript after punctuation. To avoid it, include:

```
\usepackage[superscript, biblabel, nomove]{cite}
```