# Superscripts in bibliography with bibtex too close to text

Tags: bibtex, superscripts

I have read this [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79591/superscripts-in-bibliography-with-bibtex) and I did as suggested to get my reference in the superscript, but I am not fully pleased with the effect, because when I type in `Nicholson and Shain\cite{Nicholson64}.` I get my superscript number after the dot, not before. How to force it to be before the dot?

My minmal working example is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, c5paper]{book}
\usepackage[superscript, biblabel]{cite}
\let\oldthebibliography=\thebibliography
\let\oldendthebibliography=\endthebibliography
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
    \oldthebibliography{#1}%
    \setcounter{enumiv}{28}%
}{\oldendthebibliography}

\begin{document}

\ldots it was worked out by Nicholson and Shain \cite{Nicholson64}.

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

and inside `biblio.bib` file I have:

```
@article{Nicholson64,
    journal = "Anal. Chem.",
    volume = "36",
    pages = "706",
    year = "1964",
    author = "R. S. Nicholson and I. Shain",
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `nomove` option to `cite`:

```
\usepackage[superscript, biblabel, nomove]{cite}
```

[image]