# How can I use natbib to get both superscript-style citations and "authoryear"-style citations in the same document?

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

Depending on the context, I might prefer to use superscript-style citations (i.e. `a recent paper\cite{paper} said XYZ` --> a recent paper<sup>1</sup> said XYZ) or author-year-style citations (i.e. `\citet{paper} said XYZ` --> John Smith (1990) said XYZ) in the same document. How can I do this with `natbib`?

I am aware that using `\usepackage[super]{natbib}` allows me to have superscript-citations with the `\cite` command. But this causes the `\citet` command to print "John Smith<sup>1</sup> said XYZ" instead of the above, and causes the `\citep` command to print "<sup>1</sup> said XYZ".

Is there any way I can sometimes use superscript-style citations, and sometimes use authoryear-style citations, using the `natbib` interface/some workaround?

Here's a quick example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[super,comma]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % most basic and widely used bibliography style
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref1,
    author = {Smith, John},
    journal = {Very Important Journal},
    title = {Very Important Paper},
    year = {2000}
}
@article{ref2,
    author = {Smith, John},
    journal = {Another Very Important Journal},
    title = {Another Very Important Paper},
    year = {2001}
}
\end{filecontents}

% Body
\begin{document}
  Results from \citep{ref1} and \citet{ref2} imply XYZ\cite{ref1,ref2}.
  \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Something similar was done in biblatex: http://www.khirevich.com/latex/bibliography/

Comment: Since you say you want to use `natbib` I have removed the `biblatex` tag. `biblatex` and `natbib` are two different packages and they are incompatible (`biblatex` offers an interface to emulate some of `natbib`'s behaviour, but they are still fundamentally different and incompatible). An [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) may help us to understand your question better and get started more quickly. Often solutions depend on the styles used.

Comment: @Mico Sometimes I want my citations to look like this: "a recent paper says XYZ<sup>1</sup>". This is the current default behavior of `\cite` when `natbib` is loaded with the `super` option. Other times I want to be able to do this: "according to John Smith (1990), XYZ" or this: "a recent paper (John Smith, 1990) says XYZ". These last two styles don't have to be accomplished with the `citet` or `citep` commands; perhaps they can be achieved with `\specialhackycommandA` and `\specialhackycommandB`. I am just trying to describe the behavior I desire. I am surprised this is still unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've discovered, if the `super` option of the `natbib` package is in place, both `\cite` and `\citep` generate just superscript-style numeric citation call-outs, while `\citet` generates a hybrid name-superscript citation call-out.

If `natbib`'s `super` option is in effect, the commands `\citename` and `\citeyear` remain available. The following example document defines the macros `\citeA`, `\citeY`, `\citeAYp`, and `\citeAYt` to help you achieve your formatting needs. Note that I would recommend against redefining the behavior of the package's `\cite`, `\citep`, and `\citet` directly.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{ref1,
    author  = {Smith, John},
    journal = {Very Important Journal},
    title   = {Very Important Paper},
    year    = {2000},
}
@article{ref2,
    author  = {Smith, John},
    journal = {Another Important Journal},
    title   = {Another Important Paper},
    year    = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\usepackage[super,comma]{natbib}
\newcommand\citeA[1]{\citeauthor{#1}}
\newcommand\citeY[1]{(\citeyear{#1})}
\newcommand\citeAYt[1]{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}
\newcommand\citeAYp[1]{(\citeauthor{#1} \citeyear{#1})}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb+\cite+    & \cite{ref1}\\
\verb+\citep+   & \citep{ref2}\\
\verb+\citet+   & \citet{ref2}\\
\verb+\citeA+   & \citeA{ref1}\\
\verb+\citeY+   & \citeY{ref2}\\
\verb+\citeAYp+ & \citeAYp{ref2}\\
\verb+\citeAYt+ & \citeAYt{ref1}
\end{tabular}

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If this were `biblatex` I would not be very happy with `\newcommand\citeAYt[1]{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}` for lack of support for multiple citations and proper pre- and post-note rendering, but I guess with `natbib` that is the easiest solution.

Comment: @moewe -- Thanks. The user guide of the `natbib` package discourages using `\citet` with multiple argments, unless all cited entries have the same set of authors and, presumably, differ in the values of the `year` field. The `\citeAYt` macro merely elevates this practice to "official policy". :-) Hopefully, the answer also points the OP in the right direction for creating (even) more sophisticated citation macros. A side comment: I don't understand the motivation for generating citation call-outs that are a hybrid of authoryear and numeric-superscript styles. But it's not my place to argue...

Comment: Ah, I see... I think we discussed a similar topic before, because I remember being told about this restriction. Indeed the citation style is very odd. A reader may have a hard time finding the proper reference for the author-year call-outs, but at least the sorting is not counterproductive here.

Comment: Thanks @Mico! BTW my motivation is in prose/style -- oftentimes I may want to talk about a paper in depth/explicitly, in which case the author-year citation is much more appropriate (e.g. "I am using the really cool science thing introduced by John Smith (1990)...").  But other times I may want to use a citation to offhandedly justify a statement, in which case the superscript is much more appropriate than author-year or parenthetical author-year, especially if I am citing several papers at once (e.g. "this science thing is well established<sup>1-3</sup>")