# How to get parentheses and superscript with citations in chicago reference style?

Tags: citing, natbib, superscripts

I am looking to use the "Chicago" referencing style because it has been requested by my supervisor.

I have implemented that but I want it to display the in-text citation in parentheses with the year and a superscript.

At the moment the output is as follows for a citation:

```
Daly et al. [1] 
Fadhila [2] ...
```

What I want it to display is

```
(Daly et al, 2006)^(superscript 1) 
(Fadhila, 2005)^{2}
```

and in the reference list, it should also display the numbers as it already does that.

Below is the code I have in my main file where I just \input the chapter files as I go.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[sectionbib, square, numbers, sort]{natbib} 
\usepackage{chapterbib}
```

These commands are placed in the chapter files because I want the references to be displayed per chapter.

I know an MWE would help, but I am not familiar enough with how to do it.

```
\bibliographystyle{chicago} 
\bibliography{References/References.bib}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The BibTeX `chicago` bibliography style is really old and implements the formatting guidelines of the 13th edition of the "Chicago Manual of Style". Importantly, "Chicago" is currently on the 17th [!] edition. Are you sure that adopting the obsolete 13th edition is going to cut it with your supervisor and your university? If not, you should probably switch from natbib/bibtex to biblatex/biber, especially as there is an up-to-date "Chicago" style for biblatex.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the response. I suppose it would not be a train smash if I chose a different style, as long as it is consistent and I get that citation style that I am looking for with the parentheses, year and superscript number.

Comment: @Mico I found this thread [natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420370/how-can-i-use-natbib-to-get-both-superscript-style-citations-and-authoryear-st) where you basically solved the problem with your `\citeAYp` command, it displays author name and year in parentheses.  How would you add the superscript number to the in-text citation in this case? That is all that remains in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `natbib` citation management package is loaded with the options `super` and `round`, superscript-type citation call-outs will be generated by `\cite`, with the raised numbers surrounded by parentheses. The low-level commands `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` are available as well. Thus, your preferred citation call-out form may be generate with the following code:

```
\usepackage[super,round]{natbib}
\newcommand\citeAYS[1]{(\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1})~\cite{#1}}
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{smith,
    author  = {Smith, Jane},
    title   = {Thoughts},
    year    = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{chicago} % or some other suitable bib style
\usepackage[super,round]{natbib}
\newcommand\citeAYS[1]{(\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1})~\cite{#1}}

\begin{document}
\citeAYS{smith}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```