# Citing a range of papers in superscript format

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I have seen the post [Citing a range of papers using numeric keys as in \cite{a, b, c} -> [1-3]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3871/citing-a-range-of-papers-using-numeric-keys-as-in-citea-b-c-1-3)

I want to cite a range of papers, but in superscript format like this [Superscripts in bibliography with bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79591/superscripts-in-bibliography-with-bibtex)

Can anyone please tell me how can I do that?

**EDIT:**

```
\documentclass[Afour,sageh,times]{sagej}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}


 \begin{document}

 Referring to articles\cite{art1,art2,art3}. 


 \bibliographystyle{ama}
 \bibliography{test}

  \end{document}
```

The test.bib file is:

```
  @Article{art1,
  author =   {Author, AN},
  title =    {Title One.},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     2000
 }

@Article{art2,
 author =   {Author, AN},
 title =    {Title Two.},
 journal =  {Journal},
 year =     2008
}

@Article{art3,
author =   {Author, AN},
title =    {Title Three.},
journal =  {Journal},
year =     2020
}
```

Comment: If and how that is possible depends on the bibliography/citation packages you load (`cite`, `natbib`, `biblatex`, ...) as well as the specific citation/bibliography style you are using. Please show us a small example document that reproduces your current bibliography and citation setup with as little unrelated code as possible. At the moment we cannot help you properly, because we know too little about your setup. ...

Comment: ... The question is tagged with both `biblatex` and `natbib`, but the packages are incompatible and cannot be used together (so only one of the two tags make sense for your current setup). Here the tag `mla-style` is also slightly confusing since MLA style is usually not associated with numeric citations (be it in superscript format or otherwise). MLA style uses in-text mentions of author (plus possibly work title).

Comment: @moewe Sorry, I am not using mla style, rather than ama-style referencing. And I am using natbib.

Comment: Did you try loading `natbib` with `\usepackage[sort&compress, super]{natbib}` (do not load the `cite` package, do not load `biblatex`)? If that does not help, we really need to see an example document of your setup. There are too many things that could interfere here.

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: @moewe For my example, `\usepackage[sort&compress, super]{natbib}` is not producing superscript citation.

Comment: Where did you get `sagej.cls` and `ama.bst` from? (My MikTeX system does not find them automatically, which means they are either not on CTAN or on CTAN with a license that makes distribution tricky/impossible.)

Comment: @moewe ama.bst from here: https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/ama.bst

Comment: @moewe `sagej.cls` from overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/sage (I have followed the first document style of the link).

Comment: Do you mean https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-demonstration-of-the-latex2e-class-file-for-sage-publications/jcdyknyjrkzb? The abstract has a link that apparently points to a Sage template at http://www.uk.sagepub.com/repository/binaries/SAGE%20LaTeX%20template.zip, but that link is dead for me.

Comment: @moewe Yes, I searched `sage latex template overleaf`. Does it work for you: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-demonstration-of-the-latex2e-class-file-for-sage-publications/jcdyknyjrkzb

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you load the class with the option `sageh`? If you use `sagev` that seems to select a different citation style that is sorted, compressed and in superscripts. Presumably that option should actually be used with `\bibliographystyle{SageV}` and not with `\bibliographystyle{ama}`.

Comment: @moewe I just followed the latex template of the mentioned link, there the class option is `sageh`. I will submit a manuscript in one of the sage journals, there they require ama-style referencing.

Comment: Try with `sagev` instead of `sageh` if no one told you explicitly to use `sageh`. The template says to use `\bibliographystyle{SageV}` or `\bibliographystyle{SageH}`, but if you insist you can probably also use `\bibliographystyle{ama}`.

Comment: @moewe It's working perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sagej` is a publisher class and as such already takes care of most things itself. You should not (have to) load many additional packages or make modifications in the preamble.

I could not obtain the original template from SAGE, but I used the Overleaf template version https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-demonstration-of-the-latex2e-class-file-for-sage-publications/jcdyknyjrkzb that was linked in the comments.

The user guide states explicitly

> You must select options for the trim/text area and the reference style of the journal you are submitting to.

and lists the following three options for citations

> | Option | Reference style |
> | --- | --- |
> | `sageh` | SAGE Harvard style (author-year) |
> | `sagev` | SAGE Vancouver style (superscript numbers) |
> | `sageapa` | APA style (author-year) |

You want superscript numbers, so you should use `sagev` instead of `sageh`.

Do not load `natbib`, `cite`, `biblatex` or any other bibliography/citation package yourself.

The document also suggests to use `\bibliographystyle{sageV}` in that case. (Although if you insist on using `\bibliographystyle{ama}` that should work as well. Do note though that the [`ama.bst` from CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ama) is not an official AMA style and has not been updated since 2002 according to the code comments.)

```
\documentclass[Afour,sagev,times]{sagej}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{art1,
  author  = {Author, A. N.},
  title   = {Title One},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = 2000,
}
@Article{art2,
  author  = {Author, A. N.},
  title   = {Title Two},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = 2008,
}
@Article{art3,
  author  = {Author, A. N.},
  title   = {Title Three},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = 2020,
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Referring to articles\cite{art1,art2,art3}.

\bibliographystyle{sageV}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Superscript citations 1-3.]